# Generate PDF in Ruby with tables and images

Tags: ruby, pdf

I want to generate a PDF with a huge table, in which are images on certain cells. I've tried [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/122), but the lib doesn't support images in Tables. Then I've tried [PDF::Writer](http://ruby-pdf.rubyforge.org/pdf-writer/manual/manual.pdf) but I don't find any solution to place images in tables either.

Is there a good/working solution to generate PDF documents with tables (and images in cells) with Ruby?

Comment: +1 for linking to the feature request ticket for Prawn. That way, future readers will be able to tell if it's been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try PDFKit.

https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit

Edit: [Here](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2010/06/15/rethinking-pdf-creation-in-ruby.html) is a nice description and some examples from the author.

Comment: It uses wkhtml2pdf; I'm pretty sure it can generate do what you want.